# Setting domains for feature class using ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, feature-class, domains, attachments

I am looking to setup a basic app that allows field staff to fill out a form and attach a photo in order to track certain field features.

The issue I am having is that ideally I would like to setup domains in order to have drop down menus for filling out the forms. I can certainly set this up through ArcGIS Desktop, however my licensing level does not allow for setting up photo attachments.

If I create a feature class on-line through ArcGIS Online, I can setup photo attachments, however it doesn't appear that I can setup domains via ArcGIS Online. Am I wrong in assuming I can't set domains through ArcGIS Online?

My only options seem to be either an app with no photo attachments but easy to fill in form or an app with photo attachments but a harder to fill in form.

Is it possible to set domains via AGOL?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, you are correct in that you cannot setup up domains in AGOL. However, you are along the correct path in that you can create your domains in ArcGIS for Desktop as usual then publish it to AGOL where your field workers will be able to see the drop down box in their app using Collector.

I'm not sure about the photo attachments portion, though.

Comment: -1 because you've missed OP main point, that Enable Attachments (Data Management) is not available for "Basic" license or whatever the correct name for this

Comment: Changed it to +1

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Survey123](http://survey123.esri.com/) to setup domains - use the choices sheet in the Excel file to list the domain values, and reference it via a select_one type question within the survey sheet. Then publish it as a service, and use the published feature service via the app you are using.

There is also an option to enable attachments after publishing a feature service. Once you publish the feature service, open the layer in ArcGIS Online. Then click the small arrow icon next to the layer for which you want to allow attachments and choose Enable attachments. See [this documentation](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION2_EF4F7A72F7B74E47B5CBCC1F343445E2) for further details.